# In what way is Japanese related to Sanskrit?

Tags: historical-linguistics, writing-systems, japanese, sanskrit

The Wikipedia says that Japanese katakana vowels “The gojūon inherits its vowel and consonant order from Sanskrit practice. “.   Could expert explains this in easy language?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a question about how Japanese orders its characters and how that might be related to how it is done in Sanskrit. Sanskrit and Japanese as spoken languages have almost no connection  at all except for some Buddhist vocabulary.

Answer (score 11):

Due to the study of Buddhism and its scriptures in the source language (either [Buddhist Hybrid Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_Hybrid_Sanskrit) or [Pali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali)) Japanese scholars were aware of the structure of the Indic scripts finally coming from the tradition of Sanskrit. When they created the Katakana they applied the ordering priciples of the [Devanagari Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) to it; the deviations (i.e., the ordering of the consonants s and h) can be explained by later sound shifts: The /h/ was a /p/ originally and developped via /ɸ/ to /h/, the /s/ was a /ts/ originally and thus closer to the Devanagari letter ca (च).

EDIT: Incorporated information from the comments

Comment: I think Japanese Buddhists, like other Northern (Mahayana) Buddhists, read their scriptures in Buddhist Sanskrit, not in Pali.

Comment: /h/ in Japanese comes from OJ /p/, not /f/. As far as I recall, /s/ is a merger of /s/ and /ts/, but nothing more.

Comment: @jknappen It was definitely /ɸ/ at some point, but as part of the transition from /p/ to /h/. Again, going from memory, the sound change to /ɸ/ almost certainly postdated the creation of the kana syllabaries—though I’ll grant you I have no idea if it postdated the ordering of the kanas according to their Sanskrit equivalents.

Comment: Roy Andrew Miller certainly suggests that the s-series in kana must have been something like /ts/, at least with some vowels.

Comment: Was it ordered when it was created? My hunch is that the creation predates the ordering.

Comment: Did they have no order before?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goj%C5%ABon): "The earliest example of a gojūon-style layout dates from a manuscript known as Kujakukyō Ongi (孔雀経音義) dated c. 1004–1028. In contrast, the earliest example of the alternative iroha ordering is from the 1079 text Konkōmyō Saishōōkyō Ongi (金光明最勝王経音義)." I was under the impression that the iroha ordering was older (because it's less scientific!) but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score -6):

hiragana arrived in Japan from Indian monks who were not allowed to enter China, turned to Corée and Okinawa and used a syllabary similar to Sanskrit to start a form of sound of the characters

Comment: Hiragana certainly did not arrive in Japan from anywhere: it was created in Japan from simplification of existing kana systems (such as Man'yogana). The _ordering_ of the syllabary was influenced by Sanskrit - though the i-ro-ha remained in use as an alternative ordering until quite recently.